# Regexp: replace all digits on URL after third slash

Tags: regex, url, grok

How can I replace all digits in URL after third slash, on characters #### with regexp?
In this case, the number of # must correspond to the number of replaced digits.
Numbers can be in more than one slash section.
Also, the location of the digits is not fixed, but exactly after the third slash

Examples:

```
/path/to/something/1234/end
/path/to/something/12/1234/end
```

To:

```
/path/to/something/####/end
/path/to/something/##/####/end
```

I tried to use an expression, but it does not give the desired result:

```
"(?<=/)\\d+(?=/|$), #####"
```

This regexp is needed to implement the grok pattern in Logstash (gsub function).

P.s. Why after third slash? Because because the numbers can be at the beginning, but they do not need to be changed (`/path/to_1/something/1234/end`)

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)(?:(?=\d*/)|/)|^(?:/[^/]*){3}/)\K\d` to replace with `#`. Or, maybe `(?:\G(?!^)/?|^(?:/[^/]*){3}/)\K\d(?=\d*/)` will be more precise.

Comment: The expression works on the example, but doesn't work on the real query https://regex101.com/r/7DXl5t/1

Comment: And what is the "real query"? Is it anywhere in the question?

Comment: This tweak to @WiktorStribiżew's solution should work: `(?:\G(?!^)\/?|^(?:\/[^\/]*){3}\/[^\d]*)\K\d(?=\d*\/)`, though I think he should get credit for this one. Check here: https://regex101.com/r/DQWG6y/1.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/7DXl5t/2. As far as I understand, you do not need to match digits in `/ST00006486/` and `/lk_2456882/`

Comment: On the contrary, I would also like to hide these digits

Comment: Then it is even simpler: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?:/[^/]*){3}/)\D*\K\d`, see https://regex101.com/r/7DXl5t/3

Comment: If it does not work, try to use `(?:\G(?!^)|^((?:/[^/]*){3}/))(\D*)\d` as regex and `$1$2#` as replacement. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7DXl5t/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^((?:/[^/]*){3}/))(\D*)\d
```

as regex and `$1$2#` as replacement.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7DXl5t/4).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^((?:/[^/]*){3}/))` - end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) start of string + three occurrences of `/` and then zero or more non-slash shars and then a slash char captured into Group 1 (`^((?:/[^/]*){3}/)`)
- `(\D*)` - Group 2: any zero or more non-digits
- `\d` - a digit

The replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 + Group 2 values and a `#` char.